# How to combine two data-flows in Android app architecture?

Tags: android, architecture, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

I was building a chat application in Android in accordance with the [app architecture guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture). I have stored the user's data in `Room Database` in sync with `Firebase Cloud Firestore`, and user's active-status in `Firebase Realtime Database`.

In `Datasource` layer, users' data is exposed in the form of `PagingDataFlow` and a single user's active-status is exposed in form of `Flow`. From `Activity`/`Fragment` layer, both of these combined together form a UI state. Now, either in `Repository` or in `ViewModel`, I have to combine these two and form the `UserUI` unit and pass on that flow to `View` layer. I guess I have to do this in `Repository` layer. But I have no clue how to do it.

```
       -----------------                             ------------------
       |  UserLocalDS  |                             |  UserRemoteDS  |
       -----------------                             ------------------
           ↑       |                                     ↑        |
   (no_arg)|       |Flow<PagingData<User>>        user_id|        |Flow<UserStatus>
           |       ↓                                     |        ↓
       ----------------------------------------------------------------
       |                       UserRepository                         |
       ----------------------------------------------------------------
                                      |
                                      |Flow<UserUI>
                                      ↓
                               --------------
                               | UserListVM |
                               --------------
                                      |
                                      |Flow<UserUI>
                                      ↓
                               --------------
                               |UserListView|
                               --------------
```

Each emission from `UserLocalDS` is a `PagingData<User>` which contains a paged list of `User`. For each such `User`, I have to pass `user.user_id` to `UserRemoteDS` and obtain a `Flow<UserStatus>`, which emits `UserStatus`, which has to be merged with `User` to result in a `PagingData<UserUI>`.

This is pseudocode for what is expected. But this is not proper.

```
    pagedUsersFlow = userLocalDS.getPagedUsersFlow()
    pagedUsersFlow.foreach { user ->
        userStatusFlows[user.user_id] = userRemoteDS.getUserStatusFlow(user.user_id)
    }
    pagedUsersFlow.transform { user ->
        user + userStatusFlows[user.user_id].collect()
    }
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `UserUI` and `UserStatus`?

Comment: @JulianA. `UserUI` is just `User` + `UserStatus`.

Comment: And what's the relationship between `User` and `UserStatus`?

Comment: @JulianA. They are just two plain data models related to user. I will get them from two separate sources. I don't know how to merge them.

Comment: We don't have enough information yet to answer the question of merging.  Is there only a single user in each `Flow<PagingData<User>>`?  Is there only the `UserStatus` of a single `User` in `Flow<UserStatus>`?  Do you need to use the `User` to get a `Flow<UserStatus>` of just that single user?  We need to know these answers before we can help.

Comment: @JulianA. Updated the question. Check now.

Comment: After a day long of searching for the solution, I have came to conclusion that this [could/should not be done](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#:~:text=Do%20not%20mix%20or%20combine). Thanks for all of those who tried to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following implementation:

```
pagedUsersFlow.flatMapLatest {
     flow {
         it.map { user ->
             userRemoteDS.getUserStatusFlow(user.id).onEach { status ->
                 emit(UserUI(user, status))
             }.launchIn(coroutineScope)
         }
     }
}.collect { userUI ->
    // use userUI
}
```

---

**Update**:

```
pagedUsersFlow.map {
    it.map { user ->
        val status = userRemoteDS.getUserStatusFlow(user.id).firstOrNull() ?: UserStatus("offline")
        UserUI(user, status)
    }
}.collect { pagingUI: PagingData<UserUI> ->
    // ...
}
```

The drawaback of this solution is that it will not update user status if it is changed on `Firestore`. Actually I don't think there is a good solution to what you want to achieve using `PagingData`. I would recommend to reconsider your data structures and use `List` instead of `PagingData`.

Comment: Problem with this is that the `flatMapLatest` will cause loss of the `UserUI`s of previous pages that are slow when being transformed to `UserUI`s.  In other words, I think the `flatMapLatest` may be applied too early here.

Comment: @JulianA I'm not sure, but doesn't an emission of `PagingData` contain all pages that are being displayed?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Does it?  It depends what "paging" means.  Does each instance of `PagingData` contain _all_ users?  Or does it contain a page of users, and the next page contains the next page of _different_ users.  If the latter, then you will (sometimes) lose users due to the race set up by `flatMapLatest`.  If the former, then my criticism is irrelevant.  Which one is it?

Comment: @JulianA. Ohh, okay. I'm not sure about that. But probably you are right. Each emissions only contain next page and not entire range of pages.

Comment: @Sergey. I didn't notice first, but you are finally returning/collecting a `Flow<UserUI>`. But I wanted `Flow<PagingData<UserUI>>`.

Comment: @JulianA. You are indeed correct. I have logged and verified. Each emission of `PagingData` only contains the currently requested page, and not all loaded pages.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks. I'm convinced that this what I asked, cannot be done using this `paging` api. As you said, I will try some other way for doing this. Thanks for helping though. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
val f1: Flow<List<Int>> = flow {
    emit(listOf(1, 2, 3))
    emit(listOf(4, 5, 6))
}

fun fs(i: Int): Flow<String> = flow {
    repeat((Math.random() * 10).toInt()) {
        delay((Math.random() * 1000).toLong())
        emit("_$i")
    }
}

val f2: Flow<Pair<Int, String>> = f1.flatMapMerge { l ->
    l.asFlow().flatMapMerge { n ->
        fs(n).map { s ->
            n to s
        }
    }
}
f2.onEach {
    println(it)
}.collect()
```

Sample output:

```
(5, _5)
(3, _3)
(4, _4)
(2, _2)
(6, _6)
(5, _5)
(3, _3)
```

This will produce a flow of the user updates of every user.  Each emission will contain both the user and the status.

To simplify things, take `Pair<Int, String>` as the combination of `User` and `UserStatus`, i.e. `UserUI`,  `Flow<List<Int>>` as `Flow<PagingData<User>>`, and `Flow<String>` as `Flow<UserStatus>`.

You probably shouldn't use the `Flow.*latest` operators because they will drop emissions when there's back-pressure.  And there could be back-pressure if calling `getUserStatusFlow` for an entire `PagingData<User>` is ever slower than `Flow<PagingData<User>>` is emitting `PagingData<User>>`.

You'll need a way to convert a `PagingData<User>` to a `Flow<User>`.  (I do this with `l.asFlow()`, where `asFlow` is provided by `kotlinx.coroutines`)  That should be pretty straightforward if `PagingData` is a type of collection that allows iteration.  If you don't know how to do this, ping me in the comments and I'll add it.

Comment: I wanted `f2` to be `Flow<List<Pair<Int, String>>>`.

Comment: In your example, sample output I expected was, [ (1, _1), (2, _2), (3, _3) ], [ (4, _4), (5, _5), (6, _6) ], [ (1, _1), (2, _2), (3, _3) ], [ (1, _1), (2, _2), (3, _3) ], [ (4, _4), (5, _5), (6, _6) ], [ (1, _1), (2, _2), (3, _3) ], .... 

aka, I wanted same pages to be re-emitted, with updated status values. But anyway, I got to know that it [cannot be done](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/PagingSource#:~:text=instance%20of%20PagingData.-,A%20PagingData,-can%20grow%20as) with `paging` api. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Apart from the problem with the `paging` api, what you describe as expected probably won't behave properly.  Because there's no way to guarantee when there'll be a `UserStatus` for _any_ user.  Let's say you get a `UserStatus` for the first user and then no `UserStatus` for the second user and then a `UserStatus` for the third user.  How long will you wait before giving up on getting a `UserStatus` for the second user before you are able to emit a `PagingData` with the `UserUI` of the second user?  It could be seconds, minutes, or hours.  Meanwhile, `Flow<UserUI>` is completely blocked.

Comment: My plan was :- I would never wait for `UserStatus`. By default, `UserStatus` will be `Loading`. After that, whenver 'any' status gets updated in a page, that page will be re-emitted with status of other users being the previous value.   In your analogous example, this would be, adding `.onStart { emit("__$i") }` to `fs`.